# When a couple is applied on rigid body does it always rotate about the axis passing through its centre of mass?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

[image: Image describing two cases of rotation of rods with different couples acting]

Will these $2$ rods have the same motion, i.e. rotation about their centres of mass with the same torque or will there be a difference in their axes of rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two bodies that you described will have the same motion. By the way, not just in case of couple, all bodies always roate about an axis passing through the center of mass unless the body is forcefully made to rotate about some other axis by pivoting them about some axis not passing through the center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the center of rotation of the left body will be at the mid-point between the forces. I'm not sure I can explain it, but when you try it, by placing a ruler or a pencil on a table you will see it rotates around the midpoint between the 2 F.
I wish somebody would know to draw this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the center of mass will not accelerate if the *net* force is zero (as it is with a force couple), from Netwton's 2nd law.

If the body has a center of mass at rest initially, then as a result of *any* force couple, the center of mass will remain at rest.

But a force couple produces a non-zero net torque *about* the center of mass, and thus will result in angular acceleration.

In the simplest form, this is expressed for the examples above as

$$ \tau_{\rm net} = F \left( \tfrac{L}{2} \right) = I \alpha $$

and

$$ \tau_{\rm net} = \left( \tfrac{F}{2} \right) L = I \alpha $$